# avoid picking up the current directory when using tar

Tags: unix, tar

I am trying to tar some files & folders in `.tgz` format. I am in the same directory as the files and folders.

I did -> (where file1, file2 and .file3 are files and folder1 and 2 are folders)

```
tar -czvf test.tgz file1 file2 .file3 folder1 folder2
```

I ended up with all these files and folders but also an extra `.` folder which had contents like `._.file1 , ._.file2` etc. How do i create a tar without this folder?

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to the `--exclude` option:

```
tar -czvf test.tgz --exclude "._.*" file1 file2 .file3 folder1 folder2
```

If required you could add more `--exclude` options for example:

```
tar -czvf test.tgz --exclude "._.*" --exclude ".foo*" file1 .file2 folder2
```

If you would like to tar the current directory also this may work:

```
tar -czvf ../yourdir.tgz --exclude "._*" .
```

Notice the `../yourdir.tgz` it will save the file outside your current directory.